# Dynamically add controls to a silveright StackPanel to Create a menu

Tags: silverlight, controls

hello community any one can please say how to add controls dynamically into a Stack Panel

note: what i need is i have to create a menu which get data from  database and creates menu items accordingly can any one say how can i create such menus i am new to silver light

I am using silverlight 3 beta and expression blend3 + sketch flow please help me to know how to design those

Comment: check out this

http://silverlightpopupmenu.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

Excuse the variable names, but here is a code snippet of dynamically adding items to a stack panel

```
StackPanel split = new StackPanel();
TextBlock expected = new TextBlock();
expected.Text = "Expected Final Bonus";
TextBlock meh = new TextBlock();
meh.Text = Math.Round(((QuoteData)results.First()).ExpectedBonus * 100, 2) + "%";
split.Children.Add(expected);
split.Children.Add(meh);

TextBlock disc = new TextBlock();
disc.Text = "Discretionary Percentage";
TextBlock number = new TextBlock();
number.Text = Math.Round(((QuoteData)results.First()).Discretionary * 100, 2) + "%";

split.Children.Add(disc);
split.Children.Add(number);
```

Here you can see that I also created the stack panel dynamically, however, you can also create it using XAML.

Something like this should work:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="split" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if your StackPanel is already in your XAML, handle the Loaded event:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spValue" Loaded="spValue_Loaded">
</StackPanel>

private void spValue_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = (sender as StackPanel);
    stackPanel.Children.Clear();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(XamlReader.Load(XElement.Parse(xaml).ToString()) as FrameworkElement);
}
```

The controls are created with XAMLReader from your stuff loaded from the DB.  You can adapt all that to your particular scenario (menu and menu items...)

Comment: friend devMomentum,
i will load N number of items from DB how can i add can i use foreach or for loop in urs answer XElement is the variable which gets datafrom database am i right can i use some thing like this 
private void spValue_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = (sender as StackPanel);
    stackPanel.Children.Clear();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(XamlReader.Load(XElement[i].Parse(xaml).ToString()) as FrameworkElement);
}
}
i mean XElement is the array of string taken from DB can i use like this